# Write json file using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read and write a json file using python script(I have embedded this python block inside a shell script)

test.json

> ```
> {
>   "environments": ["dev", "qa", "load", "prod"],
>   "region": ["asia", "europe", "americas", "asia-pacific"],
>   "product": ["mobile", "internet", "kiosk", "branch"],
>   "ID": ["mobile:111", "internet:222", "kiosk:333", "branch:444"]
> }
> ```

I am trying to add region(uk), before that I want to check and add if it is not avilable in list. 
Below is my python code and I am able to update the value

```
reg_val="uk"

a_dict = {}
try:
    with open('test.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        temp_list = []
        for dicObj in data["region"]:
            temp_list.append(dicObj)
        temp_list.append(reg_val)
        data["region"] = temp_list
        a_dict["region"] = data["region"]
        with open('test.json','w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(a_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True, encoding="utf-8"))
except IOError as io:
    print "ERROR: ", io
```

I was able to update the json file, but it removes the other lists.The output I see is

```
{
    "region": [
        "asia", 
        "europe", 
        "americas", 
        "asia-pacific", 
        "uk"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why not just write `data` back to the file instead of `a_dict`, which is a new dict containing only regions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just keep it simple, and only append if `reg_val` exists with the `in` operator. Then you could just dump to another file.

```
import json

reg_val = "uk"

with open('test.json') as in_file, open('out.json', 'w') as out_file:
    data = json.load(in_file)
    if reg_val not in data['region']:
        data['region'].append(reg_val)

    json.dump(data, out_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Which gives the following *out.json*:

```
{
    "ID": [
        "mobile:111",
        "internet:222",
        "kiosk:333",
        "branch:444"
    ],
    "environments": [
        "dev",
        "qa",
        "load",
        "prod"
    ],
    "product": [
        "mobile",
        "internet",
        "kiosk",
        "branch"
    ],
    "region": [
        "asia",
        "europe",
        "americas",
        "asia-pacific",
        "uk"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Meep Meep, you're fast!

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're writing `a_dict` to the file, which is initialised as an empty `dict`, then only has `data["region"]` inserted into it.

I had some code to provide as an example, but RoadRunner beat me to it (hey, he's pretty fast!).  You also need to be careful with your file-handling, as you have a READ file handler open at the same time as a WRITE file handler - this can be dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the other lists were removed is because you're using write mode instead of append mode. When you reopen your test.json file, use the code `open('test.json', 'a')` to append to test.json without overwriting what you previously wrote.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, it is not suitable to append to a json file. Instead, write everything in a single dump. I recommend RoadRunner's approach.

Comment: But this will append the json representation of the list, including the outer braces (`{`). This will cause errors later.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit my post to mention this.

Comment: I was going to suggest keeping track of the line in question, then re-write the whole thing (including) that line, but @RoadRunner also beat me to it